# How to generate Haml views instead of erb

Tags: haml

I'm building an app with Rails 2.3.4 and using

```
script/generate controller home index
```

to generate a controller and home page. I've got Haml installed. I get an erb file:

```
app/views/home/index.html.erb
```

but I'd prefer to have a Haml file generated instead, like:

```
app/views/home/index.html.haml
```

I recall Merb would generate .haml views instead of .erb if a haml gem was detected. Is this not available in Rails 2.3.4? I tried

```
script/generate controller home index --haml
```

but a "--haml" option is invalid.

Of course I can manually change my erb files to haml files but I'd rather have the generator do the work. Call me lazy. Suggestions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This gem will do the trick
http://github.com/indirect/haml-rails

Comment: Good answer for Rails 3.0. And we should be using Rails now.

Answer (score 2):

Waht actually worked for me, but in rails 3.1 is this wiki here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views
:)

Answer (score 0):

This gem [here](http://github.com/mrflip/rspec-haml-scaffold-generator) might be useful.  I don't think there is any way to do this outside of a plugin/gem.  (disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself, but came across it when I was researching the same thing)